# How to convert xsd:Date into xsd:DateTime in SPARQL (dbpedia)?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to get data about people including their birthdate and their deathdate from DBpedia, but for dates, the type returned is `xsd:Date` when I need the date in `xsd:DateTime` format.

Can we convert the result (`xsd:Date`) to `xsd:DateTime` in the query? If yes, how?

- `xsd:Date` --> `"1940-01-01"`
- `xsd:DateTime` --> `"1940-01-01T00:00:00"`

I tried the query below, but it's not working ...

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 

SELECT ?person ?name ?birthDate ?deathDate
WHERE { 
    ?person rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> 
    ?person rdfs:label ?name.
    ?person dbo:birthDate ?birthDate.
    ?person dbo:deathDate ?deathDate.   
    strdt(concat(substr(?birthDate, 7, 4), '-', substr(?birthDate, 1, 2), '-', substr(?birthDate, 4, 2), 'T00:00:00'), xsd:dateTime).
    strdt(concat(substr(?deathDate, 7, 4), '-', substr(?deathDate, 1, 2), '-', substr(?deathDate, 4, 2), 'T00:00:00'), xsd:dateTime). 
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: That is not a valid SPARQL query...what do you want to achieve by `strdt(concat(substr(?birthDate, 7, 4), '-', substr(?birthDate, 1, 2), '-', substr(?birthDate, 4, 2), 'T00:00:00'), xsd:dateTime).
    ` ?

Comment: You can convert from `xsd:date` to `xsd:dateTime` by using the `xsd:dateTime` constructor: `BIND(xsd:dateTime(?birthDate) as ?bd)` Unfortunately, DBpedia data is rubbish, and will lead to conversion errors if the date format doesn't conform to `ỲYYY-`MM-DD` . You can see that it would work in general by running `SELECT ?bd {BIND(xsd:dateTime("2017-09-20"^^xsd:date) as ?bd)}`

Comment: Thank's @AKSW  !  Do u know if it's possible to use regular expression to reject incorrect results or something like that ?

Comment: You ought to be able to use `coalesce(val1, val2,...)` to say 'If this works use it, otherwise use this', but virtuoso keeps complaining (it's an idiosyncratic implementation of sparql). You can use `(if(regex(str(?birthDate), '\\d{4}-\\d\\d-\\d\\d'), xsd:dateTime(?birthDate), ?birthDate) as ?bddt)` to protect yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(As an answer, since the comment isn't very readable)

As AKSW says, the data is slightly broken (e.g. '1800-1-1') and virtuoso complains if you try to cast `xsd:dateTime(?birthDate)`. Because of a virtuoso quirk you can't use the more pleasant `coalesce(xsd:dateTime(?birthDate), ?birthDate)` which should return the first non-empty, non-error value.

So we have to protect ourselves with a regex:

```
if(
    regex(str(?birthDate), '\\d{4}-\\d\\d-\\d\\d'),
    xsd:dateTime(?birthDate),
    ?birthDate)
```

That is: if the string value of `?birthDate` is of the right form (4 digits - 2 digits - 2 digits) then cast, otherwise use the original value.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 

SELECT ?person ?name 
    (if(regex(str(?birthDate), '\\d{4}-\\d\\d-\\d\\d'), xsd:dateTime(?birthDate), ?birthDate) as ?birthDateDT)
    (if(regex(str(?deathDate), '\\d{4}-\\d\\d-\\d\\d'), xsd:dateTime(?deathDate), ?deathDate) as ?deathDateDT)
WHERE { 
    ?person rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
    ?person rdfs:label ?name.
    ?person dbo:birthDate ?birthDate.
    ?person dbo:deathDate ?deathDate.   
}
```

[Try this in dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+xsd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E+%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++SELECT+%3Fperson+%3Fname+%0D%0A++++++++%28if%28regex%28str%28%3FbirthDate%29%2C+%27%5C%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5C%5Cd%5C%5Cd-%5C%5Cd%5C%5Cd%27%29%2C+xsd%3AdateTime%28%3FbirthDate%29%2C+%3FbirthDate%29+as+%3FbirthDateDT%29%0D%0A++++++++%28if%28regex%28str%28%3FdeathDate%29%2C+%27%5C%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5C%5Cd%5C%5Cd-%5C%5Cd%5C%5Cd%27%29%2C+xsd%3AdateTime%28%3FdeathDate%29%2C+%3FdeathDate%29+as+%3FdeathDateDT%29%0D%0A++++WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++++++++%3Fperson+rdf%3Atype+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPerson%3E+.%0D%0A++++++++%3Fperson+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fname.%0D%0A++++++++%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate.%0D%0A++++++++%3Fperson+dbo%3AdeathDate+%3FdeathDate.+++%0D%0A++++%7D+&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)